# MySQL trim multiple 0 of string?

Tags: mysql, trim

So I have a column of strings in a format like this: `'123.123.123.123.123'`.
I need to cut the string to the first two numbers like so: `'123.123'` that way I can `GROUP BY` the cut string to get the results needed.

I can do this easily by using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Version, '.', 2)` however the problem arises when the second number part has multiple 0's therefore giving me duplicate entries in the query.

e.g. `(10.00, 10.0)` and `10.404, 10.4040` etc.

Is there a way to trim all unwanted zeros off the end of the string?

**Note**: I can only use straight MySQL or functions in this case.

---

**EDIT**:
I can get the desired result by replacing the first instance of '.0', trim the extra zeros and then replace the '.0' back

```
REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Version, '.', 2), '.0', '^a')), '^a', '.0')
```

This probably is not the best option performance wise - therefore I will wait for others before accepting my own.

Comment: Your method of doing it sounds fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only working with the first two components, then convert the values to a number, say:

```
cast(substring_index(version, '.', 2) + 0 as decimal(10, 4))
```

This will give everything with equal numeric values the same representation.

EDIT:

If you want to remove the trailing zeros from the *end* of the string, you can use this trick:

```
 replace(rtrim(replace(substring_index(version, '.', 2), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

This replaces the zeros with spaces, then uses `rtrim()` and converts them back to zeroes.

Comment: This will still give me trailing zeros on the end which was the original problem. - this will also only give me 4 decimal points - which is not the desired effect.

Comment: @ChiMo . . . It will give you the *same* trailing zeros for all the values, which would seem to fix your problem.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff it would be more desirable to get the exact representation, avoiding having to use front end code to display it correctly - seeing as the result can be queried upon again when 'drilling' into more detailed information.